# Include directory missing files after building OpenCV for Android

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

I tried to build OpenCV for Android and I succeeded. What I did was I git cloned the Opencv 2.4.9 source files and then ran cmake_android.cmd. After that every thing was ok but when I tried to link the library with an Android project, I noticed that the opencv2 directory, which is contained inside the include directory in the opencv for android source code, doesn't contain the necessary modules directory, but just a opencv.hpp. Any ideas where can I find the include directory within the opencv directory?